# C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments QtConcurrent::map

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qtconcurrent

I am trying to get a basic program implementing QtConcurrent to work.
Found a lot of sites with similar problems, but none of their solutions worked for me so far.

My code:

```
void Setup::addOne(int &i)
{
    ++i;
}

void Setup::Test()
{
    QList<int> list;
    list.append(1);
    QtConcurrent::map(list, &Setup::addOne);
}
```

Trying to build it shows the following error:

```
C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

The error refers to the following lines in qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:

```
bool runIteration(Iterator it, int, void *)
{
    map(*it);
    return false;
}
```

I am working with Qt5. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-static member functions actually have a hidden argument, a pointer to the object which becomes `this` inside the function.

Unless you need to access member variables or call other member functions, I suggest you make the `addOne` function `static`.

Comment: if you *do* need to access members, wrap the method up like `[this](int &i){ addOne(i); }`